# Why am I still getting this file-upload error in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, file-upload, config

I've set up a file-upload system in a Laravel project. Smaller files upload correctly, but I'm getting the following error on the production server when I try to upload bigger files:

`The "" file does not exist or is not readable.`

After looking at several SO posts, etc., I assumed that this issue was related to either the `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` value in the `php.ini` file being too small.

However, `upload_max_filesize` is set to `5M`, `post_max_size` is set to `8M`, I am able to properly restart the Apache server, and I'm sure (after running the `php_ini_loaded_file` and `php_ini_scanned_files` functions in a PHP file on the server) that all these settings are coming from the `/etc/php.ini` file on the server.

Even so, if I try to upload a file that is about 3.6 MB, then it fails with the error message above.

What could possibly be causing this issue that I'm not thinking of? Thank you.

---

**Edit**: Here's some sample code that reproduces the error on the server:

Routes:

```
Route::get('/temp/upload-test', [TempController::class, 'uploadTest']);
Route::post('/temp/upload-test', [TempController::class, 'uploadFileTest']);
```

Controller:

```
public function uploadTest() {
    return view('uploadTest');
}

public function uploadFileTest() {
    $file = request()->file('file_0');

    if ($file) {
        $mimeType = $file->getMimeType(); // <-- This throws the error.

        return [
            'mimeType' => $mimeType
        ];
    }
}
```

`uploadTest` Blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="file">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.3/axios.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            let file;

            const process = async (formData) => {
                const response = await axios.post('/temp/upload-test', formData, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                });

                console.log(response.data);
            };

            document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
                if (evt.target.files[0]) {
                    file = evt.target.files[0];
                }
            });

            document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async (evt) => {
                if (file) {
                    let formData = new FormData();

                    formData.append(`file_0`, file);

                    process(formData);
                }

                evt.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key is that I'm using Axios to send the file to the server. This code properly returns the MIME type for all files (regardless of size) on my localhost setup, but it seems to fail for any files over 2 MB on the server, so I'm assuming it's a server config issue, but as mentioned before, the `php.ini` file seems to be set up correctly and I've restarted Apache multiple times.

And here's the start of the error in the Laravel log for anyone that's interested:

```
[timestamp] production.ERROR: The "" file does not exist or is not readable. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The \"\" file does not exist or is not readable. at /$
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/sub-folder/vendor/symfony/mime/MimeTypes.php(134): Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser->guessMimeType('')
#1 /var/www/sub-folder/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php(77): Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\MimeTypes->guessMimeType('')
#2 /var/www/sub-folder/app/Http/Controllers/TempController.php(61): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\File->getMimeType()
#3 /var/www/sub-folder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\TempController->uploadFileTest()
#4 /var/www/sub-folder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('uploadFileTest', Array)
```

---

**Edit #2**: I just confirmed with another test that Axios isn't the issue. I get the same problem when I do a standard form submission without any JS.

Comment: You can contact your hosting provider. The problem could possibly be from them.

Comment: Please also change the `max_execution_time`

Comment: Thanks, Innovin and Ken Lee. The `max_execution_time` is set to `30`, and the script throws the error above after a second or two, and the "hosting provider" is me setting up the server on an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: Can you share your code and where exactly the error occurs?

Comment: Use chunk upload for big files

Comment: Frnak, I added some sample code that faithfully reproduces the issue. Thank you. ANAS MK, how would I chunk the upload? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer. I had to run the following command before restarting Apache to get the `php.ini` file changes to take effect:

`sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service`

After I ran that command, ***and then*** restarted the Apache server after that, everything was okay.